# How to handle SO copycat fraud site?

Tags: support, copyright, malicious-links

I was just searching for a programming solution via duckduckgo and by clicking one of the top results I ended up on `stackoverflowhot.com`.
This website is an exact copy of Stackoverflow.com and only when I could not upvote an answer, I noticed that it is not the original SO website.

I think this is potentially dangerous. While I did not encounter any atempt to trick me into entering my password or install malware, I assume the intentions of the site owners are not good. Also I guess they are infringing on the copyright of SO and SO users.

So besides from raising awareness of this page, my question is: 
Is there any way to report this (besides reporting it as spam on duckduckgo)? Does Stackexchange Inc. have any policy on encountering such clickjacking sites?

Comment: Is it possible to un-close the question so I can answer it a bit better? The answer in that question you linked to says "In principle, there's actually nothing wrong with doing this. Our content is licensed under Creative Commons BY-SA 3.0 and is freely redistribituble" .... Is this really the message you want to send across? Copying ***content*** that is licensed by Creative Commons is one thing, but copying the ***whole site*** is not, and the correct answer is to use the [Contact us](https://meta.stackexchange.com/contact) link.

Comment: @user1271772 Can you post an answer on the duplicate target?

Comment: @user202729: it is certainly possible.

Comment: @user202729 no, that is already answered in the faq. Right after "How do I go about reporting these sites?" it clearly says "Please contact us directly using the on-site form." I believe user1271772 somehow missed it, but anyway posting duplicate answer there, or here, is not good.

Comment: @user1271772 no, please don't. See my above comment.

Comment: In fact the linked duplicate answers my question. I had done a search before I posted my question but obviously I was using the wrong keywords. Thanks, everybody!

Comment: @ShadowWizard: I understand that duplicate answer is not good, but there is quite a lot of reading to do here. One has to go and first read a rather long question asked by someone else, then read a mighty long answer that contains much more than just the thing we're looking for. It talks about so many different scenarios. Is it really fair to make them read all that?

Comment: @user1271772 maybe not fair. That's how this site works, it requires people to read.

Comment: @ShadowWizard: Is there anything wrong with trying to help make it easier for them when that is do-able ?

Comment: @user1271772 You can do it in a comment, that's good and I do it myself many times: closing as duplicate of a long faq and posting a "TL;DR" comment. But posting a new answer is wrong.

Comment: @ShadowWizard, I think I saw some questions here that had more than 1 answer, but I'll have to look at it later tonight when I get more spare time